# How to know whether someone is sharing login access to a resource online

Tags: authentication, networking, web

Suppose there is an online restricted resource for which you have to pay to gain access.
If I pay for the access and let my friend use my credentials to access the resource through his PC, will the authority serving the resource come to know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to detect this? Yes, but only under some circumstances.

Will it be detected in practice? That depends. Here's some examples using just the geolocated ip address and the access time.

#### Case 1

- Location: same city
- Access times: a few hours apart

The entity serving the content will see "user1" access their content from two different devices at two different times, from approximately the same geographic area. This is a normal thing.

#### Case 2

- Location: same city
- Access times: overlapping

The entity serving the content will see "user1" simultaneously accessing their content from two different devices. This is presumably not a normal thing.

#### Case 3

- Location: different continents
- Access times: a few hours apart

The entity serving the content will see "user1" access their content from two different devices at two different times, but from very different geographic areas. This could be flagged by them, but is a fairly common occurrence at this point due to VPN usage.

You can probably come up with a great many more examples like these on your own, possibly involving things other than just geolocated ip addresses and access times. As you can see, the answer to your question is that it depends (at minimum) on usage patterns.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was also having the same logic but I thought maybe there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: As @Mouli suggested, you might limit access "quantity" in some manner. Alternatively, just flag "overly high" access stats as likely abuse. Or there's the Netflix route of limiting simultaneous active logins and then just not worrying about it.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, I don't think there is a reliable way to do this technically.  Though IP address could be an option, that tremendously reduces usability and highly impractical i.e. the user won't be able to login from computers in different networks with different IPs.

Since you mention payment, a better option usually is to kind-of "game theorize" it i.e. incentivize the user to NOT share the credentials.  For example, if the publisher restricts the number of articles the user could read in a month, then sharing the login with a friend means the original user potentially gets far less value for what they paid.

Comment: I agree that there isn't a reliable way to detect this. The only feasible way according to me is the one mentioned below.